# 'Animus' — negative connotation?

Tags: nouns, connotation

The [Oxford Dictionaries entry for *animus*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/animus?q=animus) reads:

> 1. [mass noun] Hostility or ill feeling:
> 2. [mass noun] Motivation to do something:

Owing to definition 1 above, I suspect that a negative connotation inheres in definition 2. The definition doesn't elucidate or promulgate this, but this word would be too confusing if definition 2 could also refer to positive motivation. Am I right?

Comment: As an aside, in English, questions are not formed like this? I have edited your question accordingly? Please do not do it in the future? Thank you in advance?

Comment: Who says words can't mean more than one thing? There are words in English that are their own antonyms, depending on context. Consider *fast* and *cleave*, for example. There are others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't necessarily have a negative connotation, though it can have.

Meaning 1 is usually shown by words such as *against* or *towards*. Meaning 2 (which I think is rare) takes no object, or maybe an infinitive

Some of the examples from the OED (which mentions both meanings, but does not treat them as different senses):

> *I hope you will now, despite your rather evident animus against her, set this to her credit.* (1911, meaning 1)

vs

> *They have an instinctive appreciation of the animus that actuates the policy of a foreign country.* (1867, meaning 2. All the examples newer than this have  *against*.)

Having said that, the example from Thackeray (1840):

> *From the animus with which the case has been conducted,..it was easy to see the result.*

does seem to have the first meaning, even though there is no explicit object.

Comment: Is sense 1 really much less rare than sense 2? I would think of anyone who started talking about animus towards something in normal conversation as quite insufferably pompous; and even in writing, my gut feeling is that _animosity_ is far more common.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was preparing an answer to this question but this one was just as good as mine would have been. I found in COCA that of over 300 incidences of "animus" maybe 2 or 3 of them meant "animating force/motivation". The rest were clearly negatively-connotated and meant "negative feeling". The term has been used frequently in recent years in legal rulings concerning laws against same-sex marriage, and the term is reused in popular coverage of those rulings.

Comment: @nohat Still, 300 instances in COCA is not much to begin with (though I notice _animosity_ gets only about 1100, too).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet well, "insufferably" only has 65 incidences.... :-D

Comment: @nohat That only proves that I'm an insufferably pompous git, and I could have told you that without you having to go look it up in COCA. ;-)